# Sort ArrayList of ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I'm having trouble using a Comparator to sort an ArrayList of ArrayList of Objects, i have this simple code:

```
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> office = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>(15);
        ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList1 = new ArrayList<Object>(15);
        objectArrayList1.add("Denver");
        objectArrayList1.add(108);
        office.add(objectArrayList1);

        ArrayList<Object> objectArrayList2 = new ArrayList<Object>(15);
        objectArrayList2.add("NewYork");
        objectArrayList2.add(109);
        office.add(objectArrayList2);

       [[Denver, 118], [NewYork, 109]]
```

How do i sort it by the numbers or the String?

Comment: "_I'm having trouble using a Comparator_" Can you show us that code? What you posted does not show any of that.

Comment: Your first mistake is having an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>`. I can't think of a single situation where I've ever needed one. Denver and 118 are presumably related to one another in some way. That relationship should be encapsulated in a class. Then you can have an `ArrayList<City>`, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to override the compare() method using Collections.sort() and create a new Comparator. Because you are using object it's going to be difficult to write a generic sorter. Here is an example for a sort on an arrayList of a custom object

```
 Collections.sort(finalList, new Comparator<FinalAccount>()
        @Override
        public int compare(FinalAccount o1, FinalAccount o2) {
            Double o1Double = o1.reductionAmount;
            Double o2Double = o2.reductionAmount;
            return o1Double.compareTo(o2Double);
        }

    });
```

but again this is for only one type of object, generics confuse things because you may have any type of object.

Comment: Generics do not confuse things. Rather, *inheritance* confuses things (by virtue of using `Object`).

Comment: Id argue that both do in this case. If you had an array list of size 50 and it has 50 different objects in it, writing a generic comparator would be unreliable unless you implemented a VERY basic way of sorting

Comment: And that's a problem because everything implicitly is polymorphic and derives from `Object`. You shouldn't be able to have a `List<Anything>` in well-designed language, you should have to be specific.

Comment: Would it help if i make it an ArrayList of Strings?

Comment: very much so, that would allow you to sort alphabateically just use the exact same syntax I had but instead of finalList use your list of strings and instead of FinalAccount use String, also if this works and you feel comfortable with the answer, please consider accepting :)

Answer (score 0):

Your data model is a little off.
Assuming you want to store data for cities and their associated "scores" to sort on, you need a list of objects that can contain both the city and its score. This entity has to be comparable.

For e.g

```
Team implements Comparable {
 String city;
 int score;
 Team(String city, int score) {
  this.city = city;
  this.score = score; 
 }

@Override
 public int compareTo(Team other) {
   return this.score - other.score;
 } 
}
```

Now you do can sort an ArrayList of Teams

```
List<Team> teams = Arrays.asList(new Team("New York", 101), new Team("Denver", 108));
Collections.sort(teams); // sorts in-place
```

You can also use custom comparators like

```
Collections.sort(teams, new Comparator<Team>(){
@Override
public int compare(Team t1, Team t2) {
 return t1.city.compareTo(t2.city);
}
})
```